# Object 'iCrypt' can be disposed more than once

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I have seen several questions about this issue. For example:

["Object can be disposed of more than once" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982719/object-can-be-disposed-of-more-than-once-error)

But I can't quite work out what I should be doing with my code. The warning I have from code analysis is:

> 1>D:\My Programs\2017\PTSTools\PTSTools\PTSTools.cs(81): warning
>   CA2202: Microsoft.Usage : Object 'iCrypt' can be disposed more than
>   once in method 'PTSToolsClass.Crypt(string, string, bool)'. To avoid
>   generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call
>   Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 81

The method in question:

```
private string Crypt(string strData, string strPassword, bool bEncrypt)
{
    byte[] u8Salt = new byte[] { ... };

    PasswordDeriveBytes iPass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(strPassword, u8Salt);

    Rijndael iAlg = Rijndael.Create();
    iAlg.Key = iPass.GetBytes(32);
    iAlg.IV = iPass.GetBytes(16);

    ICryptoTransform iTrans = (bEncrypt) ? iAlg.CreateEncryptor() : iAlg.CreateDecryptor();

    MemoryStream iMem = new MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream iCrypt = new CryptoStream(iMem, iTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

    byte[] u8Data;
    if (bEncrypt)
        u8Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strData);
    else
        u8Data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);

    try
    {
        iCrypt.Write(u8Data, 0, u8Data.Length);
        iCrypt.Close();
        if (bEncrypt)
            return Convert.ToBase64String(iMem.ToArray());
        else
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(iMem.ToArray());
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        iCrypt.Close();
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain why I get this warning raised for the `finally` line of code?

Thank you.

Update:

Based on comments I changed it to:

```
private string Crypt(string strData, string strPassword, bool bEncrypt)
{
    byte[] u8Salt = new byte[] { ... };

    PasswordDeriveBytes iPass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(strPassword, u8Salt);

    Rijndael iAlg = Rijndael.Create();
    iAlg.Key = iPass.GetBytes(32);
    iAlg.IV = iPass.GetBytes(16);

    ICryptoTransform iTrans = (bEncrypt) ? iAlg.CreateEncryptor() : iAlg.CreateDecryptor();

    MemoryStream iMem = new MemoryStream();
    using (CryptoStream iCrypt = new CryptoStream(iMem, iTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
         byte[] u8Data;
        if (bEncrypt)
            u8Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strData);
        else
            u8Data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);

        try
        {
            iCrypt.Write(u8Data, 0, u8Data.Length);
            iCrypt.Close();
            if (bEncrypt)
                return Convert.ToBase64String(iMem.ToArray());
            else
                return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(iMem.ToArray());
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But I now have these warnings:

```
1>D:\My Programs\2017\PTSTools\PTSTools\PTSTools.cs(77): warning CA2202: Microsoft.Usage : Object 'iCrypt' can be disposed more than once in method 'PTSToolsClass.Crypt(string, string, bool)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 77
1>D:\My Programs\2017\PTSTools\PTSTools\PTSTools.cs(77): warning CA2202: Microsoft.Usage : Object 'iMem' can be disposed more than once in method 'PTSToolsClass.Crypt(string, string, bool)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 77
```

It now does not like the catch block.

Update:

Understood:

```
   private string Crypt(string strData, string strPassword, bool bEncrypt)
    {
        byte[] u8Salt = new byte[] { 0x26, 0x19, 0x81, 0x4E, 0xA0, 0x6D, 0x95, 0x34, 0x26, 0x75, 0x64, 0x05, 0xF6 };

        PasswordDeriveBytes iPass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(strPassword, u8Salt);

        Rijndael iAlg = Rijndael.Create();
        iAlg.Key = iPass.GetBytes(32);
        iAlg.IV = iPass.GetBytes(16);

        ICryptoTransform iTrans = (bEncrypt) ? iAlg.CreateEncryptor() : iAlg.CreateDecryptor();

        MemoryStream iMem = new MemoryStream();
        using (CryptoStream iCrypt = new CryptoStream(iMem, iTrans, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
                byte[] u8Data;
            if (bEncrypt)
                u8Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(strData);
            else
                u8Data = Convert.FromBase64String(strData);

            try
            {
                iCrypt.Write(u8Data, 0, u8Data.Length);
                if (bEncrypt)
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(iMem.ToArray());
                else
                    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(iMem.ToArray());
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message from code analysis is clear. Your code disposes (closes) iCrypt two times. One time inside the try block and one time in the finally block. Remove the line `iCrypt.Close();` in the try block (between `iCrypt.Write(...)` and `if(...)` and the warning will disappear.

Even better approch is a using block:

```
using (CryptoStream iCrypt = new CryptoStream(...)) {
   .... // your code without the finally block
}
```

The using will call iCrypt.Close() regardless whether and exception is thrown inside the block or not.

Answer (score 2):

[Because the `finally` block of a `try-(catch-)finally` block is always executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547791/why-use-finally-in-c), the analyzer sees this:

```
try
{
    iCrypt.Close();
}
finally
{
    iCrypt.Close();
}
```

It then correctly infers that those calls can occur in succession, causing the `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown in the second call.

So: you don't need the `iCrypt.Close()` in the `try` block, because it'll always be closed in the `finally`, whether an exception occurs or not.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling iCrypt.Close(); twice, remove the call from inside the try statement and you will be fine.