# How to get rid of "Object 'object' can be disposed more than once in method"

Tags: c#, idisposable

I am analyzing the code using Visual Studio tool and I get this message:

> Object 'FileStream' can be disposed more than once in method 'BitmapFormat.WriteBitmap(byte[], int, int)'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.

I tried to called disposed explicitly on the object but no avail.

This is the method:

```
Stream FileStream = null;
try
{
    FileStream = File.Open("finger.bmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter TmpBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(FileStream);
    TmpBinaryWriter.Write(StructToBytes(BmpHeader, 14));
    TmpBinaryWriter.Write(StructToBytes(BmpInfoHeader, Marshal.SizeOf(BmpInfoHeader)));

    //µ÷ÊÔ°åÐÅÏ¢
    for (ColorIndex = 0; ColorIndex < m_nColorTableEntries; ColorIndex++)
    {
        ColorMask[ColorIndex].redmask = (byte)ColorIndex;
        ColorMask[ColorIndex].greenmask = (byte)ColorIndex;
        ColorMask[ColorIndex].bluemask = (byte)ColorIndex;
        ColorMask[ColorIndex].rgbReserved = 0;

        TmpBinaryWriter.Write(StructToBytes(ColorMask[ColorIndex], Marshal.SizeOf(ColorMask[ColorIndex])));
    }

    //Í¼Æ¬Ðý×ª£¬½â¾öÖ¸ÎÆÍ¼Æ¬µ¹Á¢µÄÎÊÌâ
    RotatePic(buffer, nWidth, nHeight, ref ResBuf);

    //Ð´Í¼Æ¬
    //TmpBinaryWriter.Write(ResBuf);
    byte[] filter = null;
    if (w - nWidth > 0)
    {
        filter = new byte[w - nWidth];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nHeight; i++)
    {
        TmpBinaryWriter.Write(ResBuf, i * nWidth, nWidth);
        if (w - nWidth > 0)
        {
            TmpBinaryWriter.Write(ResBuf, 0, w - nWidth);
        }
    }

    TmpBinaryWriter.Close();
    FileStream.Close(); // <----- THE WARNING IS HERE
}
finally
{
    if (FileStream != null)
        FileStream.Dispose();
}
```

If I remove the `try finally` block, the same happens. Even if I use `using` statement.

How can I avoid it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has so many [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5bc%23%5d%20can%20be%20disposed%20more%20than%20once%20in%20method%20) I can't even pick one.

Comment: You ARE disposing twice.  `FileStream.Close()` is effectley the same as `FileStream.Close()`.

Comment: `BinaryWriter` will dispose the underlying stream. Which is your `FileStream`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Object can be disposed of more than once" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982719/object-can-be-disposed-of-more-than-once-error)

Comment: Unrelated: Try to use the ["using"-statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may happen because you potentially try to execute

`FileStream.Close()`,
and

`FileStream.Dispose()`

There is no point using Dispose in your case, you can just use the Close method.
The close method will execute the Dispose method with 'true' value.

Please watch this explenation of 'FileStream.Close()' method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328800(v=vs.71).aspx

> This implementation of Close calls the Dispose method passing a true value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid off this line. You call dispose in finally block which will ALWAYS run. So you can delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of a `FileStream`, you don't need to dispose it to close the file, you only need to use the Close method.